# Can I redefine a private method from a parent class using Byte Buddy?

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

Based on the idea of [Can I redefine private methods using Byte Buddy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795109/can-i-redefine-private-methods-using-byte-buddy), I would like to redefine a private method from a parent class.
Is that possible? Or it's like the chicken and egg problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: It’s not clear what you are asking. A `private` method is only relevant to its declaring class, which is the class you have to redefine. Whether this class is a superclass of another class, is irrelevant.

Comment: Because A's private method in its turn call other package protected and private methods which I do not want to replace or copy I need to redefine A's private method in B(a subclass)

Comment: There is no such method in `B`. A `private` method of `A` exists only in `A`. The only possibility to solve your task would be to replace `A`’s `private` method with a method that does a `this instanceof B` check and delegates to the old code, if the check evaluate to `false`. I don’t know whether ByteBuddy supports this kind of Instrumentation, but it looks like a questionable design anyway.

Comment: Whether this question makes sense or not ByteBuddy fails with a   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the schema (add/remove fields)

Comment: Perhaps it helps to show what you have tried…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private methods are not dispatched virtually, therefore, you cannot change the dispatch of the private method within the subclass. The only way to do this, would be to hardcode a conditional dispatch into the private method directly.

You can do so, by using Byte Buddy's `Advice` class in combination with a Java agent. The Java agent would look like the following:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
  .disableClassFormatChanges()
  .with(RedefinitionStrategy.REDEFINITION)
  .type(is(ClassWithPrivateMethod.class))
  .transform((builder, type, cl, module) -> {
     return builder.visitor(Advice.to(MyAdvice.class)
                                  .on(named("privateMethod")));
   }).install(inst);
```

where the code of `MyAdvice` is inlined in the befinning of the method named `privateMethod`. The conditional dispatch would look like the following:

```
class Adv {
  @OnMethodEnter(skipOn = OnNonDefaultValue.class)
  static boolean intercept(@This ClassWithPrivateMethod self) {
    if (self instanceof ParentClass) {
      // Your code
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

By returning true and by using the skip coniditon, you only execute the actual code if `false` is returned.